# Making a box in python with controlled inputs from user

Tags: python

I am trying to make a box where the user inputs the width, height, what kind of symbol the box should be made out of and the fill(inside the box). I am a new python coder, so any suggestions would be great, but the more novice level responses the better so i may learn and not skip into far advance techniques.

```
  def main():
        width = print(int("Please enter the width of the box: "))
        height = print(int("Please enter the height of the box: "))
        symbol =  print("Please enter the symbol for the box outline: ")
        fill = print("Please enter the symbol for the box fill: ")
        for a in range(width):
            for b in range(height):
                if i in #some condition here
                    print(symbol)
                else:
                    print(fill)
    main()
```

My projected input should be:

```
width: 4
height: 4
symbol: #
fill:1
####
#11#
#11#
####
```

Comment: So what is the exact problem with your code? What is happening, what errors are you getting, ...? (At least your `or` clause seems to be wrong, but everything else we need more information)

Comment: StackOverflow is a site to get help with specific questions you have regarding a specific problem with your code. I'd check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which might be better suited for what you need. Just make sure to read the rules there, as you should have done here. This will likely be flagged and closed as it's not really on-topic for this site.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I'm going to take out the or clause. but the original problem still stands

Comment: The original problem being what exactly? You have shown some code (which has some issues) but not told us what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I apologize, I am having problem continuing with the for loop and if and else statement, I don't know if I am on the right track and I don't know how to proceed. like I said I am stuck at this part

Comment: Just get rid of the useless loops: `print width*symbol+"\n" + (height-2)*(symbol+(width-2)*fill+symbol+"\n") + width*symbol`

Comment: @jil , I want to use the loops at least the for loop because I wanted to do it this specific way, is there any way to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    # input is your friend here 
    width = input("Please enter the width of the box: ")
    #width = print(int("Please enter the width of the box: "))
    # input etc.. 
    height = print(int("Please enter the height of the box: "))
    symbol =  print("Please enter the symbol for the box outline: ")
    fill = print("Please enter the symbol for the box fill: ")
    #since you'll be printing rows of text you should probably flip these loops
    for row in range(height):
    #for a in range(width): 
        for col in range(width):
        #for b in range(height):
            #   i ??? huh where did this come from ?
            #if i in [0, width-1] or [0, height-1]:
            # descriptive variables can only help
            if row in [0,height-1] or col in [0,width-1]:
                print(symbol)
            else:
                print(fill)
```

Comment: def main():
    # input is your friend here 
    width = input("Please enter the width of the box: ")
    #width = print(int("Please enter the width of the box: "))
    # input etc.. 
    height = print(int("Please enter the height of the box: "))
    symbol =  print("Please enter the symbol for the box outline: ")

Comment: I wasn't paying attention and I need to replace the prints with inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input("Enter number")` to get input from the user. You should first loop on height then on width. To print with no new-line use `end=""` as a parameter to `print`. You used `i` instead of `b` and `a`. That's about it I think. Next time ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    width = int(input("Please enter the width of the box: "))
    height = int(input("Please enter the height of the box: "))
    symbol = input("Please enter the symbol for the box outline: ")
    fill = input("Please enter the symbol for the box fill: ")
    dictionary = []
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            if row in [0, height-1] or col in [0, width-1]:
                dictionary.append(symbol)
            else:
                dictionary.append(fill)

    def slice_per(source, step):
        return [source[i::step] for i in range(step)]
    sliced = slice_per(dictionary, width)
    for x in range(len(sliced)):
        print("".join(sliced[x]), end="\n")
main()
```

Output - 5, 5, #, 0

```
#####
#000#
#000#
#000#
#####
```